# Unable to use Phone Call as Facebook AccountKit Verification option to create account

Tags: javascript, facebook, phone-call, account-kit

I am using Facebook's accountkit to create an account. I want to test the fallback option of using a voice call should the SMS not come through (or if not available) however when I select the "Did not receive code" (which I do receive but for sake of testing, I say no) and then opt to receive a voice call; nothing comes through on my handset. I am using the sample JS code and PHP that comes in the tutorials

I had a friend test on their mobile number and they did not receive a call either but did receive the SMS

Here are screenshots of the verification process. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnHO1.jpg

I receive no phone call at any point. Where I should do (to then enter the code you'd hear the call). The number I have been testing with is linked to my FB account as well.

```
AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
    AccountKit.init(
        {
            appId:"removed", 
            state:"removed", 
            version:"v1.3",
            fbAppEventsEnabled:true,
            redirect:"http://removed.foo.bar",
            debug:true
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/faq#faq_456777481336175 they limit the amount of calls send to a number, but with having a role in your app and the number added to your account, that should not be the problem. You are receiving the initial text message on your phone fine though, right?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/faq#faq_1038525459588951: _“In some other cases, an SMS could be delayed due to routing issues or regional issues in the end users' locale.”_ - something similar could affect calls as well. Can you try with a phone with a different carrier maybe? Sometimes those are the issue as well.

Comment: @04FS I receive the text messages fine; but just opt to say I don't receive them to test the call option.

Also, a friend has test and they had the same issues with being able to get the text and no call.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the setup for the AccountKit

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Account Kit currently supports some limited locales for Phone Call verification. Check your locale code which you have configured in your settings and here is the official documentation about Phone Call Locale Support:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/languages#call

Comment: I have tried using en_GB in the locale (I am UK based) but still not getting anything through sadly (apologies for the delay in replying)

Comment: Are you using any CMS? or do some custom coding?

Comment: Basic linux/PHP hosting. Custom code which is pretty much a copy paste from FBs own sample code but the documentation is a little thin when it comes to the voice verification side of things other than what locales are supported

Comment: But I am also using Facebook Account Kit for a long time on my website and it is working fine. A voice call is also a great method if It takes so much time to deliver OTP to your phone number. Does your login work perfectly?